# Колонки одинаковой ширины Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

В  Bootstrap v4 есть возможность задать колонки . При тестировании верстки в Firefox возникала проблема с  колонками одинаковой ширины: три колонки должны отображаться в одному ряду, а в firefox такие колонки отображаются друг под другом, т.е каждая колонка растягивается на всю ширину оберточного контейнера . Подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Ниже приложены скриншоты, наглядно демонстрирующие то как колонки  одинаковой ширины отображаются в firefox и в chrome

[image: firefox]
[image: chrome]

Comment: Лучше бы приложили код который отображает проблему. Ванг тут нет.

Comment: Возможно ваша версия firefox старая